# Hausdorff distance

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, fractals

Let $A=\{(x,y)∈R^2: x^2+y^2\le4\}$  and $B=\{(0,y)∈R^2:|y|\le3\}$.
Determine Hausdorff distance between $A$ and $B$.

I wrote $d(2)(B,A)=((0,3),A)=((0,3)(0,2))=1$.
         What about $d(A,B)$?
         $d(2)(A,B)=((2,0),B)=((2,0)(0,0))=2$. Am I right here?

Then the Hausdorff distance would be $2$

Comment: $d(A,B)= d(B,A)$. If $d$ is the Hausdorff distance. If you mean something else by $d$, which is likely, you better say what it is.

Comment: d(2) is the Euclidean distance

Comment: You are writing $d(2)(A,B)$ when you should have $\max \mathrm{dist}(a,B)$.

Comment: wrote d(2) as definition in my work book for Hauddorff distance is d(H)=max{d(m)(A,B),d(m)(B,A)}   where d(m) is Euclidian distance

Comment: That is kind of an unusual notation. Would you mind giving the title of the work book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct but your solution needs some clarification.

Since $A$ and $B$ are closed you need to find the point $a \in A$ that is furthest from $B$ and the point $b \in B$ that is furthest from $A$. You can draw a picture to see that $\max \mathrm{dist}(a,B) = 2$ which is attained at $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$, and that $\max \mathrm{dist} (b,A) = 1$ which is attained at $(0,3)$ and $(0,-3)$.  The Hausdorff distance is $$d(A,B) = \max \left\{  \max \mathrm{dist}(a,B) , \max \mathrm{dist} (b,A) \right\} = 2.$$